# Open a Map Url on a native device Map app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-native

**Q:**
I need to open this kind of link on the Native Map app. Can you tell me what plugin should I use here?

`https://www.google.com/maps?q=15405 Hebbe Ln+Au...`

I have used the [Capacitor Browser plugin](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/browser#install) and it works nicely on Android devices with the above URL. i.e. it shows Google Web map. But on the iOS device, it shows not have a valid URL error on the console and not showing in-app browser.

Any clue here, please?

**Solution:**

```
 this.inAppBrowser.create(url, '_system');
```

Comment: try this plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Do I need to do any modifications to my URL or will it work as it is? I think the Capacitor Browse plugin also does the same no?

Comment: Yes, I in my personal Experience Capacitor browser Plugin have Some issue dont know what. some time is throw error and in Firefox it always ask to open as popup etc.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Yes, it is working perfectly fine. Please put it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: Cordova Browser Plugin:

[Cordova in-app-browser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser)

```
const options: InAppBrowserOptions = {
   zoom: 'no',
   location: 'yes',
   toolbar: 'yes'
 };

const browser = this.iab.create(url, '_blank', options);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Capacitor solution

For capacitor, you'll be using the [launch-navigator](https://github.com/danielsogl/awesome-cordova-plugins/blob/master/docs/plugins/launch-navigator.md) library

```js
import { LaunchNavigator } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/launch-navigator/ngx'
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core'

constructor(
  private _launchNavigator: LaunchNavigator
) {}


public openMap(destination: string) {
  if (Capacitor.getPlatform() === 'web') {
    // To be able to test it on your laptop, remove if not needed
    window.open(`http://maps.google.com/?q=${destination}`)
  } else {
    this._launchNavigator.navigate(destination)
  }
}
```